# Could not locate named parameter

Tags: java, hibernate

I have the following query:

```
<named-native-query name="GET_Objects_REPORT">
    <query>
        <![CDATA[
               SELECT *
               FROM KAP.VC
               JOIN KAP.V ON VC.ID = V.ID
               JOIN KAP.VI ON VC.ID = VI.ID AND (VI."DATETIME" BETWEEN :startDate and :endDate)
         ]]>
    </query>
</named-native-query>
```

While executing the query, I get the following exception:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: could not locate named parameter [startDate]

```
public List<Object[]> getAllObjects(final Date startDate, final Date endDate) {
    final Query q = em.createNativeQuery("GET_Objects_REPORT");
    q.setParameter("startDate", startDate);
    q.setParameter("endDate", endDate);

    return q.getResultList();
}
```

Could you please advice what is the problem of my query?

Comment: Either you don't have a parameter called startDate, or it's in a different location.

Comment: No I passed the parameter with the same name

Comment: @user2490510 post complete code

Comment: You are creating a native-query whereas you want a named query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQL query is `GET_Objects_REPORT` (which is not valid SQL), there is no `startDate` parameter.

You need to use `em.createNamedQuery("GET_Objects_REPORT")`

Comment: Why it is not a valid SQL , am adding the native query in XML and called it from the DAO. and according to the parameter the parameters are define by q.setParameter("startDate", startDate);

Comment: Please see the second sentence.

Answer (score 0):

That won't answer the question as to why the query is not found while in a XML file (orm.xml ? is it valid according to its schema ?), but you can put your named queries, native or not, in the entity they belong to (this is not a requirement) instead of `orm.xml` or `persistence.xml`.

```
@Entity
@NamedNativeQueries({
@NamedNativeQuery(name="Foobar", query = "...")
})
public class MyEntity {

}
```

(by the way, sorry for my previous (deleted) answer. It was not pertinent, and wrong).